# Reorder the clusters in stacked bar plot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked

Let say I have these datasets:

```
test  <- data.frame(person=c("0-4", "5-9", "10-14"), 
                value1=c(100,150,120),  # male   
                value2=c(25,30,45) ,    # female
                value3=c(25,30,45),     # male
                value4=c(100,120,150),  # female
                value5=c(10,12,15),     # male
                value6=c(50,40,70))     # female
```

Using ggplot2 I create a clustered stacked barplot. My R code is this:

```
library(reshape2) # for melt

melted <- melt(test, "person")

melted$cat <- ''
melted[melted$variable == 'value1' | melted$variable == 'value2',]$cat <- "sub group 1"
melted[melted$variable == 'value3' | melted$variable == 'value4',]$cat <- "sub group 2"
melted[melted$variable == 'value5' | melted$variable == 'value6',]$cat <- "sub group 3"
melted$gender <- ''
melted[melted$variable %in% sprintf("value%i",c(1,3,5)),]$gender <- "female"
melted[melted$variable %in% sprintf("value%i",c(2,4,6)),]$gender <- "male"


p = ggplot(melted, aes(x = cat, y = value, fill = gender)) 

p + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') +   facet_grid(~ person) + 
scale_fill_manual(values = c("orangered","dodgerblue2")) + 
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'))
```

I have the following graph:

[image]

As you can see that person group is arranged as 0-4, 10-14, 5-9. I want it to be arranged as 0-4, 5-9, 10-14. I had checked the `str()` and it show the variable as factors. My question is:

1. Any idea on how to reorder the person variable as 0-4, 5-9, 10-14?
2. How can I name my graph title, x-axis, and y-axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need to reorder your grid:

```
levels(melted$person) <- c("0-4", "5-9", "10-14") # change the order of the levels
```

When you don't know how to change the order of a `factor` always print the `levels` and look how are they ordered.

With `labs` you can change the axis and title:

```
p = ggplot(melted, aes(x = cat, y = value, fill = gender)) 

p + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') +   facet_grid(~ person) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("orangered","dodgerblue2")) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white')) + 
  labs(title="abc title", x="aaa",y="bbb") 
  #+theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) # center title
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It really helps. Forgot about the `levels`. Besides, how can I make the graph title to be in centre?

Comment: adjust it in the `theme`: `+theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))`. Plenty of stuff that you can customize here.